Saving data from an HTML form
I am trying to save data from an HTML form.  I found this solution here on stackoverflow
I want to use the CacheData function (shown below) but when I run my code, I keep getting an error that serializeObject is not a function (shown below).
my HTML form has the id="settingsInput"
Why is the CacheData() function from the above link not working properly?  My form has number inputs, radio buttons, a date picker, an options dropdown, and a checkbox. only the radio buttons have inital picks set as default that I want to capture when the page loads, as they will be used immediately in fuction that is called when the body of the page loads.
<body onload="getLocation()">

    <form id="settingsInput" class="dropdown contents" autocomplete="on">

function CacheData() 
{
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
        alert("in CacheData");
        var formObject = $('#settingsInput').serializeObject();
        localStorage.setItem('settingsObject', JSON.stringify(formObject));

        jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
            var formData = {};
            var formArray = this.serializeArray();
            for (var i = 0, n = formArray.length; i < n; ++i)
                formData[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
            return formData;
        };
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }

}


Shadows_test3.html:3404 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).serializeObject is not a function
at CacheData (Shadows_test3.html:3404:42)
at savePosition (Shadows_test3.html:746:20)

I have tried calling the loadData() function from the same link mentioned above first, but CacheData still does not work.  I have moved each of those two functions in the above link to separate functions that each individually check if the typeof(Storage) !== null as the first check inside each function
// Loading data into form
function dataLoad() 
{
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
        if (localStorage.getItem('settingsObject') !== null) 
        {
            var inputParse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settingsObject'));
            $.each(inputParse, function(key, value) {
              var field = document.querySelector("[name=" + key + "]");
              if (field.type == 'radio' || field.type == 'checkbox') {
                field.checked = field.value == value;
              } else {
                field.value = value;
              }
            });
        }
    }
    else 
    {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }

}

// Saving data from form
function CacheData() 
{
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
        alert("in CacheData");
        var formObject = $('#settingsInput').serializeObject();
        localStorage.setItem('settingsObject', JSON.stringify(formObject));

        jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
            var formData = {};
            var formArray = this.serializeArray();
            for (var i = 0, n = formArray.length; i < n; ++i)
                formData[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
            return formData;
        };
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }

}

could that have broken the CacheData() function?  I do not get any errors when calling dataLoad().

Please provide the full code for the page otherwise it is hard to help. It seems you made the same mistakes as the author of the question you refer to in your question. Read the answer to that post.

I cught that mistake.  I have corrected it and this problem is resolved.

You're trying to use $('#settingsInput').serializeObject() before defining jQuery.fn.serializeObject.
So, ensure that jQuery.fn.serializeObject is defined before you call it in CacheData.
Like:
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
     var formData = {};
     var formArray = this.serializeArray();
     for (var i = 0, n = formArray.length; i < n; ++i)
        formData[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
     return formData;
};

function CacheData() 
{
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
         alert("in CacheData");
         var formObject = $('#settingsInput').serializeObject();
         localStorage.setItem('settingsObject', JSON.stringify(formObject));
    }
     else 
    {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
     }

}


Thank you Coding Enthusiast.  That fixed my issue.
